# Using append to create a list from a line of text

Tags: elisp

I want to create a list of words from a line of text delimitted by tabs. I want to basically split the line into atoms, split by tab.

The code below is sort of pseudocode but is this the best approach to do this type of thing?

Here is my first attempt:-

```
(defun get-hdr()
    ;obviously point must be positioned on correct line
    (let (mylist)
      (while(not (end-of-line)
         (while(re-search-forward ("[A-Za-z]+[^\t\n]" nil t)
           (append (match-string 1) mylist)      
         ))
      ))
   )
)
```

How do I get my function to return the list, mylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just evaluate it at the end of the loop.

```
(defun get-hdr ()
  (let (mylist)
     (while (not (end-of-line))  ; missing closing parenthesis added
        (while (re-search-forward ("[A-Za-z]+[^\t\n]" nil t)) ; ditto
           (setq mylist (append (match-string 1) mylist)) ) ) ; note setq
     mylist) )
```

It is customary to just use `cons` instead of `append` in this sort of scenario, though; then at the end, you might want to reverse the list.

```
(defun get-hdr ()
  (let (mylist)
     (while (not (end-of-line))
        (while (re-search-forward ("[A-Za-z]+[^\t\n]" nil t))
           (setq mylist (cons (match-string 1) mylist) ) ) )
     (reverse mylist)) )
```

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html which discusses the functionality of `append` in a wider context.

In many scenarios, your function should not mess with the user's regex match data or buffer position; consider adding [`save-excursion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html) and perhaps [`save-match-data`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Match-Data.html) wrappers around the `let` form.

For your stated purpose, though, perhaps all you need is

```
(split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position)) "\t")
```

([Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html#index-split_002dstring-244))